# Is it safe to bypass login on development environment?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a site in django and need to login with different user  profiles to test it. Currently I set the password of all users on my database to a string that django decrypt and interpret as "1234".
To avoid that, I wrapped the default login in the function below. Is it safe to have this code on production?

```py
def login(request, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.contrib.auth.views import login as django_login
    from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
    if settings.DEBUG:
        redirect_to = request.POST.get(redirect_field_name, request.GET.get(redirect_field_name, ''))
        if request.method == "POST":
            user = request.POST.get('username', '')
            user = Usuario.objects.filter(cpf=user)
            if user.exists:
                user = user.first()
                user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                auth_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

    return django_login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Don't forget to secure your development environment from external prying eyes: YOU think it's just development and only being used by you, but if it's visible to the outside world, even on a non-standard port, it will get hacked by bots.

For that reason, I don't ever recommend short cutting passwords or security.

Answer (score 0):

You must read about [Unit Tests on Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#tips-for-writing-tests)

So you can write a procedure to create some users, and test login with then, and after all you can delete that user's tests

This way you do not need to create a lot of users with password `'123'` in their database

Comment: Just a random happy-because-I-squashed-a-critical-infrastructure-bug-that-was-plaguing-for-weeks addition: I highly recommend factory_boy for unittest factories.

https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy